# Problem with a Handler(ImageView)

Tags: android, handler

I want to show 2 images (one when connected and the second when disconnected) and i'm using a handler to handle that, however, i'm not having any of the 2 images showen, don't know why :.

```
private Runnable handleUpdateStatus = new Runnable() 
    {     
        Boolean mRegistered;

        public void run()
        {
            ImageView statusImageDisplay = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.connected);
            if (mRegistered)
            {
                statusImageDisplay.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.connected));
                Log.i("CONNECTED","IMAGE SET");
            }
            else
            {   
                statusImageDisplay.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.disconnected));
Log.i("DISCONNECTED","IMAGE SET");
                }
            }

    };
```

Changing image code excerpt:

```
    public void onRegistrationDone(String localProfileUri, long expiryTime) {
            updateStatus("Enregistré au serveur.");
            Log.d("SUCCEED","Registration DONE");
            mRegistered = true; 
            mRegistrationUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(handleUpdateStatus);
            mRegistrationUpdateHandler.postDelayed(handleUpdateStatus, 4000);
}
```

What to do when the registration failed? this code:

```
public void onRegistrationFailed(String localProfileUri, int errorCode,String errorMessage) {
updateStatus("Enregistrement échoué.  Veuillez vérifier vos paramètres.");
Log.d("ERROR REGISTRATION",errorMessage);

mRegistered = false;
mRegistrationUpdateHandler.removeCallbacks(handleUpdateStatus);
mRegistrationUpdateHandler.postDelayed(handleUpdateStatus, 2000);
     }
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/sipLabel"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/connected" android:src="@drawable/connected" 
        android:layout_below="@id/sipLabel" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="0.35" 
        android:gravity="center" android:visibility="invisible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Any idea please of how solving this problem ?
Thank you very much.

Comment: @rekaszeru: have you corrected the code? (you edited it :\ )

Comment: I've formatted the xml code to be more readable, and replaced the `</tag>` close tags of the empty elements (to use `<[...] />`). You can check out the modifications by clicking on the time-link after the "edited" word.

Comment: @rekaszeru: Clear ;). But any idea please of the source of the problem ? :\

Comment: what happens? Is that run method get called (the Log appers)?

Comment: @rekaszeru: this is the main problem, the Log messages doesn't appears, in the onRegistrationDone function i have other code that consists to change the status of a Textview, it changes, the function is well executed, but not the lines that changes that image.

Comment: Would you please edit your question, and share these codes as well? (All the relevant code from your activity) Thank you!

Comment: @rekaszeru: All the necessary code is present now, please see my first post.

Comment: why do you need the `handleUpdateStatus`'s `mRegistered` field? As far as I can see it doesn't change anywhere...

Comment: @rekaszeru: mRegistered variable controls the 2 images: if it's true then i have to show the first image(green/connected), if it's false i have the red/disconnected image in the UI. It changes in the onRegistrationDone and in onRegistrationFailed functions.

Comment: For this ro be true, those two methods must be implemented inside the Runnable (but it's not). There is no way to access a custom member of an anonymous class from outside! I think you have a variable with this name in your activity too, and you are changing its value. Try removing that member declaration from the anonymous runnable, or make that class an inner class with name, and set its `mRegistered` value as `handleUpdateStatus.mRegistered = true;`, resp. `handleUpdateStatus.mRegistered = false;`

Comment: @rekaszeru: but all posted code is in the same class with Boolean mRegistered; and Handler mRegistrationUpdateHandler; as 2 global variables meaning that if a function modify mRegistered for example it will be modified in the whole class. I hope that i'm correct here :\ no?

Comment: That is correct in case the mRegistered member is not also declared inside your `Runnable` class! But it is: you should remove that! Please see my post for a working code :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You (must) have your `mRegistered` variable declared twice, and while you're setting the value for the global one (the one declared inside your `Activity`), you examine the value of the other one, declared inside your `handleUpdateStatus Runnable`.

You should clean up your code a bit:

- remove the `mRegistration` declaration
  from your `Runnable` implementation,
  `// Boolean mRegistered;`
- set the image drawable via resource
  id,

and it will work:

```
private boolean mRegistered;
private Runnable handleUpdateStatus = new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        ImageView statusImageDisplay = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.connected);
        if (mRegistered)
        {
            statusImageDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.connected);
            Log.i("CONNECTED", "IMAGE SET");
        }
        else
        {
            statusImageDisplay.setImageResource(R.drawable.disconnected);
            Log.i("DISCONNECTED", "IMAGE SET");
        }
    }
};
```

This is all you need to change (assuming, that your layout really contains an image with id `connected`).

**Update**
As about `mRegistrationUpdateHandler`, you should declare it as a global variable of your `Activity` (either final or initialized inside the `onCreate` method):

```
private final Handler mRegistrationUpdateHandler = new Handler();
```

or

```
private Handler mRegistrationUpdateHandler;
```

Comment: thnak you very much for your answer, but just other thing please: the handleUpdateStatus variable should i define it as global variable like  private Handler mRegistrationUpdateHandler; ? The onRegistrationDone and onRegistrationFailed functions uses it.(because it keeps not working)

Comment: I did so, and thought you have it that way in your code as well. Please see my update for reference.

Comment: YOU ARE A GENIUS. Thank you very much it works now. My dream is to become a good developper like you :) (it's not a compliment because you are so patient on your answers and you always try to help here in stackoverflow, you answers are always detailed). Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :)) I learned a lot here too, and with these questions I still do / train (Android is not school material yet, so I guess this is the best place to gather the best practices).